# How to save an image from control of another window with a button click?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: HERE IS THE SCREENSHOT OF MY ISSUE...]

I have a winform app with few controls that loads an image and a datagrid to enter data.
Issue: **I want to save that image from my winform app when I click a button**.

So far Im able to find the source window handle in C# code but do not know how to find that control and save the image...

I know I have to use winapi methods but do not know which ones...

Kindly provide some input or a sample code. I have attached the sample screenshot!!

Thank you...

Comment: So you have two independent applications, right?

Comment: Taw, yes both are separate winform apps

Comment: Did you write both? Can you make them communicate, like passing over the image path?

Comment: Dimi Takis, I have no control or code of the source app...

Comment: Can you assume that the scr app is fully visible? Is the displayed image good enough? (ImageBox may crop or stretch the image and chang the pixel depth..!) - Then one would 1) get the handle e.g. from the title 2) get the current bounds rectangle and 3) take a screenshot of that area..

Comment: Did you resolve your problems? If the answers to my questions were yes you can train the app to get the rectangle you want. If you need to access at controls level [see here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/790966/Hosting-And-Changing-Controls-In-Other-Application) - The exe you download would help to identify the control window..

Comment: Using UI Automation, you can access any (non-drawn) component of another application. If the external application is a WinForms one, you can also access the controls by handle, making it even simpler to get a control's content. The InvokePattern to click a Button is instead the same.

Comment: TaW & Jimi, your shared info in generic to window controls and handles but I need picturebox specific resolve, Moreover the picturebox control is inside a panel which has a class and scrollable pattern. Im not able to move ahead as I dont know what to code further and how because UIA coding is not easy to get along :(